# Filtering a pyspark DataFrame where rows are within a range of another DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to retrieve all rows from one DataFrame (`df1`) such that its `id` is within +- 10 of any value in the `id` column of another DataFrame (`df2`).

Example:

```python
df1.show()
#+-----+---+
#| word| id|
#+-----+---+
#|apple| 10|
#|  cat| 30|
#+-----+---+ 

df2.show()
#+----+---+
#|word| id|
#+----+---+
#|some| 50|
#|jeff|  3|
#| etc|100|
#+----+---+
```

Desired Result:

```python
+-----+---+
| word| id|
+-----+---+
|apple| 10|
+-----+---+
```

This is because `"apple"` was within 10 of `"jeff"`.

As you can see, a row is good if the `id` in `df1` meets the criteria for any `id` in `df2`. The two DataFrames are also not necessarily the same length.

It's already clear to me how to do something like an `isin` or an `antijoin` for exact matches but I am not clear on this more lenient case.

Edit: A new thought I had was that if there is no pre-built or clean way to do this, there is probably support for complex filtering based on defined functions if they're parallelizable. I will begin down that google trail and update if I find a way in that direction.

Edit: So far, I've stumbled upon `udf` functions but I haven't managed to get it to work yet. I think I need to make it accept a column and not single numbers somehow. Here is what I have so far..

```python
columns = ['word', 'id']
vals = [
     ("apple",10),
     ("cat",30)
]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

vals = [
     ("some",50),
     ("jeff",3),
     ("etc",100)
]

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

def inRange(id1,id2,delta):
    id1 = int(id1)
    id2 = int(id2)
    return id1>=id2-delta and id1<=id2+delta
inRangeUDF = udf(inRange,BooleanType())

df1.filter(inRangeUDF(df1.id,df2.id, 10)).show()
```

This currently throws the error

> ```python
> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 10 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass in a DataFrame to a `udf`. The natural way to accomplish this is to use a `join`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1.alias('l').join(
    df2.alias('r'), 
    on=f.abs(f.col('l.id') - f.col('r.id')) <= 10
).select('l.*').show()
#+-----+---+
#| word| id|
#+-----+---+
#|apple| 10|
#+-----+---+
```

I used `alias` to avoid ambiguity in specifying the DataFrame column names. This joins `df1` to `df2` where the absolute value of the difference between `df1.id` and `df2.id` is less than or equal to 10, and selects only the columns from `df1`.